# Solving a equation set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For any positive integer $m$, let $y=y(z)$ be a complex function, such that
\begin{align*}
 \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} \frac{dy}{dz}+y^m=1,
    \\ \\
   \frac{d\log(y)}{dz}=\frac{m^2e^{-mz}}{1-e^{-m^2z}}, \\
\end{array} } \right.
\end{align*}
with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow \infty}y(z)=1$. Does this function $y(z)$ exist?
For example, if $m=1$, we have $y(z)=1-e^{-z}$. If $m=2$, we have $y(z)=\tanh(z)$.

Comment: The function $1-e^{-z}$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-e^{-z})$ does not exist. May be you mean $\lim_{x\to+\infty,\ x\in\Bbb R}$?

Comment: Using $$\frac{d \log y}{dz}= \frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dz}$$ in the second equation leads to $$\frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{m^2 e^{-mz}}{1-e^{-m^2z}} y.$$ Then, using the first equation, we obtain that $y$ is defined implicitly by the relation $$\frac{m^2 e^{-mz}}{1-e^{-m^2z}} y=1-y^m,$$ which agrees with your result for $m=1$.